# Store RichTextBox data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, richtextbox

How do I store and retrieve data from SQL to be displayed in a `RichTextBox`?

I mean, how do I bind the `RichTextBlock` directly to the ViewModel that exposes the XPS/RTF/binary?

Note: I prefer storing it in binary/XPS/RTF format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly don't forget binary XPS RTF formats are not human readable. 
This may annoy you later. This choice is not always better.

You will not bind a RichTextBlock indeed. You bind your RichTextBox to a RTF or some provider object such as RTFProvider and bind your bussiness object to this Provider.

I used Telerik's RTF provider here

```
<telerikDocumentsRTF:RtfDataProvider 
RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=KTSBasicEditor, Path=Editor}" 
Rtf="{Binding AGREEMENTCONTENT, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```